# How to Remove Authentication for a single Report in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

i have implemented the Form Based Authentication for my Report Server(SSRS),
now my question is **how to remove authentication for a single report.**

i have deployed one report in the report server and i want to view it from external network without asking any username/password for that particular report..!

if i gave `<authentication mode="None" />` in web.config file this will remove all the authentication which i don't want.

i tried this also but it's not working

```
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ssrs-anonymous-authentication-problem-solved-frans-van-der-geer
```

please help..

Comment: You can use Report Manager and provide/remove access to that custom forms based user

Comment: the particular report should view to everyone without authentication, i dont want to remove particular user.

Comment: Oh, now got your point...

Comment: what is <deny users= setup?

Comment: Where you are getting error after allowing anonymous authentication? Did you tried debugging by attaching the custom code to your ssrs?

Comment: Basically anonymous authentication will effect to all the reports, but my concern is for only single report i need anonymous authentication rest all will be using form authentication. i have two reports one report for internal users(Form authentication), another one for external Users(No authentication)

Comment: I imagine it would be easiest to setup an instance of SSRS that hosts this report that you could configure for anonymous access. That may seem like overkill for one report, but I have the feeling this won't be the only report that will need this, so it could be worth the effort.